# Calling java servlet from sap Fiori project

Tags: java, ajax, sapui5

I have created a SAPUI5 project and deployed on SAP FIORI. On the project I try to call a java servlet class through ajax called "**ExampleSap**" but I get an error message '**404 (NOT FOUND)**', this is strange because on my local webserver (tomcat 8.0) it works. 
Here is my code:

**Example.controller.js**

```
onPressButton: function (evt) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ExampleSap',
        type: 'GET',
        success : function(data) {
            alert("OK");
        },
        error : function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

ExampleSap.java

```
public class ExampleSap extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  //do something
     }
  }
```

Comment: It says you deployed your SAPUI5 project on “SAP FIORI”.
Are you referring to Fiori Launchpad, WebIDE, SAP Cloud Platform, …?
Could you please post the complete error message e.g. from console.log, where it says, which HTTP request failed?

Maybe the following links might be helpful:
[Calling Servlet in SAPUI5 application shows 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924069/calling-servlet-in-sapui5-application-shows-404-error) & 
[SAP UI5 – Calling Servlet using JQUERY AJAX](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/16/sap-ui5-calling-servletwhich-returns-single-value-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: yes fiori launchpad. the complete error is: "https ://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/MYProject/src/test/ExampleSap/" 404 Not Found. I am trying to cal through ajax this class but it seems sapui5 doesn't recognize it. This happens only on fiori launchpad not on my tomcat.

Comment: Where is the location of ExampleSAP ?
Do you find it at this path: 
/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/MYProject/src/test/ExampleSap/ ?

Comment: here is the location of my java servlet: https://ibb.co/i6VDCF

Comment: What happens if you enter the exact URL from your error message: "https ://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/MYProject/src/test/ExampleSap/"
in your browser both on your frontend and on your gateway client, where the Fiori Launchpad is located?

Do you get a response?
Do you get a cross origin error?

The name of your controller is “Example.controller.js” or “Example1.controller.js”?

Comment: Does it work, if you specify the full path "https ://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/MYProject/src/test/ExampleSap/" in your Example.controller.js ?

  _$.ajax({ url : 'https ://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/MYProject/src/test/ExampleSap,_
 as seen [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/23/consuming-web-service-in-sapui5)?

Comment: if I type the url on the browser it says "not found". No cross origin error. The name of controller is Example1.controller.js. Tried that to type all the url on ajax but it doesn't work. I think sap fiori doesn't recognise my java classes. Do I need some kind of a installation on my sap to make it read java classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151080/discussion-between-manuel-k-and-sap-fiori-crew).

Comment: If the URL is not working in your browser, it also cannot work in FLP.
Therefore we first need to find the correct URL, which should also work in your browser.

What happens, if you replace “MYProject” in your URL with “SapExample1” ?
The idea is, to specify the correct path to your servlet, so that the browser can find it.

If you enter this URL: "https ://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/ SapExample1/src/test/ExampleSap/"
in your browser on your frontend, do you also get a “404 – Not found” error ?

Comment: I wrote MYProject just for an example. the real url it's with SapExample1

Comment: In the very first step, we need to specify the correct URL, so that the browser can find your servlet.
As long as the URL does not work in the browser, it cannot work in FLP.

So please verify the complete path in the URL for any typos.
How would you call your servlet from a browser?

Comment: is there any kind of installation that I have to do to make sap fiori recognize my java classes?

Comment: I think, the answer from Vijayendra Gade [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924069/calling-servlet-in-sapui5-application-shows-404-error)
describes pretty good the issue.
Is both your UI5 app and FLP deployed on SAP Cloud Platform ?